# How to tell springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin to generate YAML instead of JSON?

Tags: json, spring-boot, yaml, springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin

I am using the `springdoc-maven-openapi-plugin` this way:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <apiDocsUrl>http://localhost:9090/v3/api-docs</apiDocsUrl>
                <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/my_open_api_specification/</outputDir>
                <outputFileName>my_open_api_specification.yml</outputFileName>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This results in an OpenAPI doc in the target folder with a name having a suffix "*.yml*" but in fact it is a JSON.

How can I tell the plugin to effectively create the doc in YAML format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://localhost:9090/v3/api-docs is the default api-url, which generates JSON.
To create YAML just use http://localhost:9090/v3/api-docs.YAML

Comment: OMG. That was too easy, wasn't it? LOL

Comment: Yes it was. I had the same problem weeks ago and was searching for hours ... I'll never forget it. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The question is about compile-time generation.

For compile it will be like:

```xml
<configuration>
    <apiDocsUrl>http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs.yaml</apiDocsUrl>
    <outputFileName>openapi.yaml</outputFileName>
    <skip>false</skip>
</configuration>
```

`apiDocsUrl` should ends with `.yaml` otherwise it generates JSON in yaml file

Expect by running:

```sh
./mvnw springdoc-openapi:generate
```

In `./target/openapi.yaml` the spec in yaml format

See https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin/issues/12 for more