# How to force springdoc-maven-openapi-plugin to generate YAML file?

Tags: yaml, springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin

This is a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68741352/how-to-tell-springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin-to-generate-yaml-instead-of-json) one on the same subject.

I have actually managed to generate a YAML file successfully using the solution for the answer above. Suddenly, when I was going to demo to my peers, the generated file was JSON.

The code section is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <apiDocsUrl>http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs.yaml</apiDocsUrl>
        <outputFileName>openapi.yaml</outputFileName>
        <outputDir>${project.basedir}/api-docs</outputDir>
        <apiDocsUrl>http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs</apiDocsUrl>
        <skip>false</skip>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Even though the `<apiDocsUrl />` states `.yaml` (or `.YAML`), still the generated output is a `JSON` file.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good look at the snippet above, the answer was really obvious. The `<apiDocsUrl />` line is duplicated. The first instance sets the output file as `.yaml` and the second as `.json`.